# Consider an experiment in which a person first specifies a number of dollars

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, game-theory, utility

Consider an experiment in which a person first specifies the number of dollars x and then observes the value of a random variable Y. Suppose that if Y >= x, he receives Y dollars as his reward. If Y < x, he receives a random reward X having some given probability distribution. It is assumed that the random variables X and Y are independent. Show that in order to maximize the expected utility of his reward, the person should specify a number x such that U(x) = E[U(X)].

Comment: I don't think this is specified clearly.  What is $z$, and what happens if $Y\geq x$ _and_ $Y<z$?  Why not just choose $x\rightarrow-\infty$, as there appears no reason to choose a large value of $x$.  I assume small-$x$ is distinct from big-$X$.

Comment: Sorry, I have made a mistake. It is Y < x

Comment: The equation $U(x) = E[U(x)]$ is wrong and should be ignored.  Nevertheless you can solve this problem:  Please write down the expected reward as a function of $x$.  Then you can differentiate with respect to $x$ to maximize the reward.  It may help to assume $Y$ is a continuous-type random variable with PDF $f_Y(y)$.  The resulting optimal $x^*$ will indeed satisfy a certain equation, but it is not $U(x)=E[U(x)]$, that looks like a typo/incorrect version of what the true $x^*$ will satisfy.  Also, since $X,Y$ are independent, we only care about $E[X]$ (distribution of $X$ is irrelevant).

Comment: @Michael sorry again, last equation should be like that U(x) = E[U(X)]. Meaning it is the expected reward of probability distribution